# How to get my dynamic generated controls value in asp.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, web-deployment

I have gone through many articles and similar kind of stack over flow questions. Almost I spend more than a day trying to find the solution, all goes in vain.
First I should tell you what I am trying to make.
[There a simple grid having a text box currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfDAN.png)

Similar to this [article](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Add-new-Row-to-GridView-on-Button-Click-in-ASPNet.aspx)

So when I put some value to text box it generate these text boxes and checkbox within that row.[(image related to above description)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R5VCF.png)


There are events firing when text box value get changed , second when add new row is clicked.(Currently ignore delete button event).


What I earlier planned was like this, create controls in every postback,I have saved first row text box values in a viewstate. I create these dynamic controls in grid-row-bound function. So I create no of controls as according to value in viewstate stored value. 
I thinked that on event function call I will first store the value of current controls then recreate all controls with same id and put back the value.So problem I am facing is that I can't find my controls on event fire. You can see in these two pic what happening because of that [1st pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bd6Q.png) [2nd pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2wVC.png).

If you want to see the code , please comment of which sections you want to see the code or full code

Here the link to the code [click here](https://1drv.ms/f/s!AoQmOkpNF33Shr9hi7Q2NJIoy-9HWw)

Comment: Please share your code what you have done do far!!!

Comment: @ShakirAhamed I have added code link in the last line. If you find any difficulty, please notify me